# java: putting icons in .jar files so that Windows Explorer can recognize them?

Tags: java, windows, swing, user-interface, icons

Windows knows where to find icons in .exe or .dll files. Is there any way to set up icon resources in a .jar file so that Windows can recognize them? (I'm interested in answers for XP or Windows 7)

Comment: I distribute Folders with *.jar, properties Files, bat file that create the ShortCuts to the desktop and as Menu Item with Icons

Comment: Is this for a Swing application?

Comment: yes, it's a Swing application. The application itself has an icon, and I start it with a .bat file that executes `java -cp SomeLongClassPath --lots-of-other-options`, but I'd like to use the icons present in the .jar file for a shortcut to the .bat file. I guess if I have to, I can manually extract the icon from the .jar file, but I was just wondering if there was something I could do to the .jar file to embed a Windows-readable .ico file there.

Answer (score 2):

[Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) can install images to use for a desktop shortcut and menu item.  JWS also supports a splash screen that can be shown while the application is loading (and/or updating new classes).  The support for icons applies to any desktop PC platform for which Java is available (caveat: If the OS supports that functionality).

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite what you asked for, but I recommend using an executable wrapper like [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).

It will execute your Java app from a .exe and will include your icon like any other windows executable does.